# no GameScene.swift or GameScene.sks files

Tags: swift

Following a tutorial on YouTube for Swift. Trying to make a game. The tutorial shows a GameScene.swift file and a GameScene.sks file and mine are not showing. Is there a setting somewhere that I've missed? The only thing different from a single-page app setup is the view controller is now named GameViewController.swift.

Watching this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sjh-IV5IamY

I'm in Yosemite and Xcode 6 Beta 2.

Thanks!

Comment: To have those files created for you, you have to select the "Game" template when you create the project. If you haven't done this, you should be able to create a second project to copy off of, and modify your existing project to include all necessary files and code from the temporary project.

Comment: I selected the game template. Everything else set up fine (GameViewController) except those two files. I added and wrote GameScene.swift, but I don't know what the .sks file is.

Comment: When you created the project, what "Game Technology" did you select? And it's an archivable version of the scene. You can add one through the new file menu.

Comment: The Game Technology was the problem. I had selected SceneKit instead of SpriteKit. Thanks!

Comment: Answer your own question and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Like  0x7fffffff♦ said, the issue is the Game Technology, needs to be SpriteKit (not SceneKit).

Answer (score 0):

Select SpriteKit in Game technology instead of the default option which is SceneKit.